# How to start DeviceWatcher in MAUI?

Tags: c#, .net, usb, hid, maui

So I've managed to create a platform-specific service which task is to communicate with an USB device via HID. As the platform-specific code doesn't work as described in MAUI docs, I've done it by DI in app builder:
`.AddSingleton<IHidCommunicationService, HidCommunicationService>();`. [Thanks to this mate:)](https://msicc.net/invoke-platform-code-in-a-maui-app-using-the-built-in-dependency-injection/)

The communication works fine but now I want to refresh devices list at runtime and to do so I wish to use `DeviceWatcher` in my `HidCommunicationService`. And here's the issue: when I try to fire the device watcher by using `Start()` method I get this error: *A method was called at an unexpected time*.

I've tried the same code in WPF app and it works fine:

```
string aqsFilter = HidDevice.GetDeviceSelector(usagePage, usageId, vendorId, productId);
DeviceWatcher deviceWatcher = DeviceInformation.CreateWatcher(aqsFilter);
deviceWatcher.Start();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `deviceWatcher.Start()` has to be fired after adding at least one event handler to `deviceWatcher`'s events: `Added`, `Removed` or `Updated`.

> WinRT information: At least an Added, Updated or Removed event handler must be registered before a watcher can be started.
> A method was called at an unexpected time.

And it should be fired from UI thread to work properly:
`Application.Current.Dispatcher.Dispatch(() => deviceWatcher.Start());`

Comment: Please mark the reply as answered so that it can help others who have similar problems. Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: I must wait at least two days to do so:)